# SyntaxError : Unexpected end of input node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I use c9.io to run this script, and i get this Error . I was trying to find the error by myself but it seems impossible to me because code is too big, if anyone can help me i would be grateful.

**Error**:

> Debugger listening on [::]:15454 /home/ubuntu/workspace/server.js:341
>   });   ^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
>       at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Timeout.Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:604:10)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:386:14)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
>
> Process exited with code: 1

**Full code:**

```js
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000);
var request = require('request');

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'dimas08',
 password : 'test',
 database : 'csgjp',
 charset  : 'utf8_general_ci'
});

connection.connect();

var sitepath = "gambt-dimas08.c9users.io"; // Path to your website, without www or http:// | Example: csgoresorts.com
var JackpotTimer=120;
var playersRequired=2;
var endtimer = -1;
var disablecredits = -1;
var allowdeposits=1;
var mindeposit=25;
var maxdeposit=10000;
var rsecret='mariusmoga'; // Change this to the same thing you have in your Endround.php!

function DisableCreditBets()
{
 allowdeposits=0;
 io.emit('disablecredit');
}

function addslashes(str)
{
    str=str.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\');
    str=str.replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');
    str=str.replace(/\"/g,'\\"');
    str=str.replace(/\0/g,'\\0');
 return str;
}

function randomString(length, chars) 
{
    var mask = '';
    if (chars.indexOf('a') > -1) mask += 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    if (chars.indexOf('A') > -1) mask += 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    if (chars.indexOf('#') > -1) mask += '0123456789';
    if (chars.indexOf('!') > -1) mask += '~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:";\'<>?,./|\\';
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += mask[Math.floor(Math.random() * mask.length)];
    return result;
}

function EndGame()
{
 endtimer = -1;
 proceedWinners();
 setTimeout(function()
 {
  io.emit('enablecredit');
  allowdeposits=1;
 },12000);
 
}

function ResumeJackpot()
{
 connection.query('SELECT `starttime` FROM `jackpotgames` GROUP BY `id` DESC', function(errs, rowss, fieldss)
 {
  if(errs)
  {
   return;
  }
  var timeleft;
  if(rowss[0].starttime == 2147483647)
  {
   timeleft = JackpotTimer;
  }
  else
  {
   var unixtime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0);
   timeleft = rowss[0].starttime+JackpotTimer-unixtime;
   if(timeleft < 0)
   {
    timeleft = 0;
   }
  }
  if(timeleft != JackpotTimer)
  {
   endtimer = setTimeout(EndGame,timeleft*1000);
   console.log('[SERVER] Restoring the latest game with '+timeleft+' seconds left!');
  }
 });
}
ResumeJackpot();

function proceedWinners()
{
 console.log('[SERVER] Ending current game & choosing winner.');
 var url = 'http://'+sitepath+'/endround.php?secret='+rsecret+'';
 request(url, function(error, response, body)
 {
  if(error)
  {
   console.log('Couldn\'t end round, error: '+error);
   return;
  }
  if(response)
  {
   io.emit('jackpotanimation');
  }
 }); 
}


io.on('connection', function (socket)
{

 console.log('connection');

 
 socket.on('jackpotanimation',function(status)
 {
  io.emit('jackpotanimation',status);
 });
 
 socket.on('showchat',function(status)
 {
  var data;
  try
  {
   data = JSON.parse(status);
  }
  catch (e)
  {
   return console.error(e);
  }
  status= JSON.parse(status);
  if(status.messageid && status.room>-1)
  {
   
   messageid=status.messageid;
   roomid=status.room;
   if(messageid>0 && roomid>-1)
   {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `id`='+connection.escape(messageid)+' ', function(err, row, fields)
    {
     if(row.length!=0)
     {
      part=row[0].PlayerID;
      var timenow=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
      started=row[0].time;
      since=timenow-started;

      if(since<5)
      {
       console.log('showchat');
       io.emit('showthechat',{ messageid: messageid, roomid: roomid });
      }
      else
      {
       console.log('timer');
      }
      
     }
     else
     {
      console.log('row lenght');
     }
    });
   }
   else
   {
    console.log('missing room  message');
   }
  }
  else
  {
   console.log('missing room or f message');
  }
 });
 
socket.on('showmssages',function(data)
{
    connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `admin`="1" WHERE `steamid`="'+data+'"', function(err, rows, fields) {
}); 
 
 socket.on('showmessages',function(status)
 {
  socket.emit('showthemessages',status);
 });
 socket.on('processdeposit',function(status)
 {
  
  if(allowdeposits==0)
  {
   return;
  }
  var data=status;
  data.steamid=addslashes(data.steamid);
  data.amount=addslashes(data.amount);
  data.secret=addslashes(data.secret);
  if(data.amount>=mindeposit && data.amount<=maxdeposit)
  {
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `steamid`="'+data.steamid+'"', function(err, row, fields)
   {
    var timenow=Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000);
    updated=timenow+1;
    lastaction=row[0].lastaction;
    if(timenow<lastaction)  
    {
     return;
    }
    connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `lastaction`="'+updated+'" WHERE `steamid`="'+data.steamid+'"', function(err, rows, fields)
    {
     if(row.length!=0)
     {
      var as=row[0].account_secret;
      var ban=row[0].ban;
      var credits=row[0].credits;
      var steamname=row[0].name;
      if(steamname)
      {
       steamname=addslashes(steamname); 
      }
      var avatar=row[0].avatar;
      console.log(as);
      console.log(data.secret);
      if(as==data.secret)
      {
       if(ban==0)
       {
        if(credits>=data.amount)
        {
         connection.query('SELECT * FROM `jackpotgames` ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1', function(err, row, fields)
         {
          var unixtime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0);
          current=row[0].id;
          var timeleft;
          if(row[0].starttime == 2147483647)
          {
           timeleft = JackpotTimer;
          }
          else
          {
           timeleft = row[0].starttime+JackpotTimer-unixtime;
           if(timeleft < 0)
           {
            timeleft = 0;
           }
          }
          if(timeleft>5)
          {
           connection.query('UPDATE `users` SET `credits`=credits-'+data.amount+' WHERE `steamid`="'+data.steamid+'"', function(err, row, fields)
           {
            if(!err)
            {
             key=randomString(32, '#aA');
             connection.query('INSERT INTO `jackpotdeposits` (gameid,userid,username,useravatar,skin,cost,date,assetid,offerid) VALUES ("'+current+'","'+data.steamid+'","'+steamname+'","'+avatar+'","Credits","'+data.amount+'","'+unixtime+'","4961","'+key+'")', function(err, row, fields, result)
             {
              if(!err)
              {
               connection.query('UPDATE `jackpotgames` SET `value`=value+'+data.amount+', `skins`=skins+1 WHERE `id`="'+current+'"', function(err, row, fields)
               {

               });
               connection.query('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS playersCount FROM `jackpotdeposits` WHERE `gameid`=\''+current+'\'', function(err, rows)
               {  
                players = rows[0].playersCount;
                if(players == playersRequired && endtimer==-1)
                {
                  console.log('[SERVER] Starting the countdown for Game #'+current+'');
                  endtimer = setTimeout(EndGame,JackpotTimer*1000);
                  disablecredits = setTimeout(DisableCreditBets,115000);
                  connection.query('UPDATE `jackpotgames` SET `starttime`=UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE `id` = \'' + current + '\'', function(err, row, fields) {});
                  io.emit('updategameinfo','');
                }
                else
                {
                 io.emit('showthedeposit',''+data.steamid+'/'+key+'');
                }
               });
              }
              else
              {
               console.log(err);
               return;
              }
              
              
             });
            }
           });
          }
          else
          {
           
          }
         });
    
         
        }
       }
      }
     }
    });
   });
  }
 });
 socket.on('showdeposit',function(status)
 {
  var array=status;
  io.emit('showthedeposit',status);
 });
 socket.on('updatecredits',function(status)
 {
  socket.emit('updatethecredits',status);
 });

});

function inArray(needle, haystack)
{
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
 {
        if(haystack[i] == needle)
  {
            return true;
  }
    }
    return false;
}

setInterval(function ()
{
    connection.query('SELECT 1');
}, 3600000);
```

Comment: You should really combine conditions to limit the high levels of nesting, deep nesting makes debugging problems like this difficult (while increasing the likelihood of experiencing them): `if(as==data.secret && ban==0 && credits>=data.amount)`

Comment: Yah thats true Dont do alot of nesting. You can also use helper functions like  find if data is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - I think I found it. You did not close the io.on function. Try adding:

```
});
```

Right before the inArray function at the bottom of the code. Let me know if this fixes it.

Or it could be right before the `socket.on('showmssages',function(data)` depending on where that function should close. But that is the issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am  certain the error i brought by the fact that one of your braces did not open and close. Try to look at `line 341 of server.js` and try to match it with the opening brace. You dont have to go through all the code. You will soon find it.

Comment: line 341 is the last line and it's empty

Comment: Correct - so it means it is somewhere deep in the code. I am looking for it now